# How to enable Wifi Access Point / Hotspot on my Moto Droid (2.2) without editing the Kernal or flashing the ROM?

Tags: wi-fi, motorola-droid, tethering, wifi-tethering, wifi-hotspot

I want to enable the Wifi Access Point (AP) functionality on my Moto Droid.  I don't mind rooting but I'd like to do this without having to edit the kernel or having to flash the ROM.  I have seen apps that enable wifi tethering but they require a netfilter enabled kernel.

Is this possible?  If it is, how do I get it done?

Here are a few points I want to clarify because I anticipate several people telling me to use PDAnet, which is a great app that I love but does not fit my needs here...

1. I want to enable my Droid as a Wifi AP, not just tether via wifi.  The point of this is that I want to be able to connect devices that are capable to connecting to wifi without having any client software on them.
2. PDAnet doesn't allow for wifi tethering at all.
3. Verizon does not offer Wifi AP service on the Droid 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I first rooted my Droid (with EasyRoot), I remained on the stock ROM until I got annoyed by the OTA update message (and ended up switching to CM6).

However, I was able to use [Wireless Tether](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wireless-tether-for-root-users/android.tether) without doing anything else.  No new kernel, no mods, nada.  Just root on vanilla Android.

If you've already updated to the latest version of Android via OTA, then I'm pretty certain you'd have to downgrade your phone to get root to work unless there is a new method to get root now.  I know for a fact that EasyRoot no longer works with the OTA update.

Comment: Uh oh, I didn't realize that EasyRoot didn't work anymore.  I never got the most recent 2.2 OTA but I just got a new replacement Droid that arrived with FRG22D.  According to [Unstable Apps](http://www.unstableapps.com/?p=81) I should only have to flash back to the earlier 2.2 FRG01B version to get rolling.

Comment: Which Kernel version is running on your Droid?

Comment: Currently I'm running ChevyNo1's Ultra Low Voltage 800mhz kernel.  I get really good battery life out of it just running it at the normal 550mhz.  Tried the 1ghz and my phone kept rebooting/wasn't stable.  But before I switched to this I was just using the stock kernel (which also only lets you overclock to 800 mhz). If you're interested in a new kernel, Chevy's kernels provide lots of options (ultra low, low, medium voltages all the way up to 1.25ghz if your phone can run them stable).

Answer (score 0):

I believe SuperOneClick works for rooting the Motorola Droid on 2.2.

http://shortfuse.org/?page_id=2

After rooting your phone, you can use Wifi Tether for Root Users.

https://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/